# Clipping line layer based on polygons with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

I have a line layer and a polygon layer. Both files have the same SRS. I want in a new shape file only the lines covered by the polygons.

I tried in QGIS the `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip` tool but I only get an empty shapefile.

How do I do this with QGIS?

[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: 2.0.1-Dufour on OS X 10.9.

Comment: It turned out that my line layer is a multistring and the QGIS clipper doesn't process multistring properly. I converted it to singleparts and then it worked.

Comment: can you please indicate where and how to transform from multistring to a singleparts? thanks

Comment: @Patribo In QGIS go to `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to singleparts`

Comment: Just a note for someone totally new to QGIS (or as dense as me in finding things!)... the polygon drawing tool is on the edit dropdown menu... took far too long to find.  (And as noted, you need a layer first to put the polygon in, generally Layer>Create Layer>Temporary Scratch Layer)... then Vector>Geoprocessing Tools>Clip and pick the Input Layer you want to clip and use your temporary layer as the output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip` tool

Input is your roads layer, clip layer is the polygon layer.

[image]

Put the line's layer in "input vector layer" and the polygon's layer in "Clip layer"

Comment: I tried that. I only get an empty shapefile. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are they the same projection?

Comment: Yes, they are. And if I do it the way you showed (Input vector layer = polygon, Clip layer = line), I get the same polygon layer in return as I put in.

Comment: The problem was that my line layer was multistring and the clipper didn't process that properly. After converting it to singleparts it worked they way you described it.

Comment: I was also returning an empty shapefile. My problem was I had failed to stop editing my newly created mask layer.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I tried your suggestion, but only Brideau's suggestion (in another answer) worked for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 13):

This gave me endless hours of frustration, and the above answers (even the ones in the comments) didn't work for me either, but I found my own solution that did the trick.

It turns out that to do an intersection or a clip between two layers, they must be **saved on disk with the same CRS**. So even if they look like they overlap in QGIS, it may be doing it's own "On the Fly" transformation to align them.

To fix this, do this for each layer:

1. Right click, **Save as...**
2. Set the format to ESRI Shapefile, pick a file name, and pick a CRS that you will use for all the layers. Click **OK** to save, and load that file.
3. Repeat for the other layer, selecting the same CRS.
4. Use the clip tool with the new layers. This should do the trick.

If you want to see if the 'On the Fly' transformation is what's causing you trouble, do this:

1. Go to the **Project** menu, and click **Project properties...**
2. Go to the **CRS** tab
3. Uncheck **Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation** and click **Apply**, **OK**

If your CRS's weren't the same, the layers should no longer overlap. You can see the position of either layer by right-clicking the layer and going to **Zoom to Layer**. When you load the two files with identical CRS, they should align perfectly.

Comment: Suggestion by Nathan W did not work for me and your suggestion worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the intersect feature. Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect.

- Input layer is your line
- Intersect layer is your polygon
- browse a document folder and save (preferred filename) in the Output Shapefile.