# Why can't I clip my Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I've tried all of these solutions ([How to clip a line layer based on polygons with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/how-to-clip-a-line-layer-based-on-polygons-with-qgis)) and still can't clip a shapefile. I'm trying to create a coastal shapefile for one region (NW France) from a world coastline. I created a custom rectangle to use as the clip extent and used `vector> geoprocessing> clip` to attempt the clip. Still no progress. Has anyone had success using other techniques or can anyone see a problem with my method?

I'm using QGIS 2.12.

Comment: Maybe there's geometry errors in either or both the shapefiles? A quick check is to use the **Check Geometry Validity** from the toolbar (_Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity_). Could you perhaps share your shapefiles on a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: Have you verified that all of the data is in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Resolved. The validity check brought up a number of issue with my custom polygon. After redrawing and using vector>geoprocessing>clip it worked

Comment: I am a new user of 36.8.1.
I have the same problem using the QGIS top down tools.
I found the work around by using the SAGA tool.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved. The validity check brought up a number of issue with my custom polygon. After redrawing and using vector>geoprocessing>clip it worked

Comment: Just had the same problem, tried everything like resaving the shapefile, restarting qgis. Checking validity found a problematic node. After I deleted it the clip worked as intended