# How to cut out a small section in my shapefile?

Tags: qgis, clip, qgis-2.12

I have a shapefile of a whole region. Since every change I do require a lot of loading time, I would like to cut out one small section which I actually need and create a new shapefile - the rest I could delete. Is it possible to cut out a square and save it as a new, smaller shapefile?

I have seen the “Clipper” – Tool, but for that  I thought that I need another shapefile or a map so that I can lay them together… I need something very simple (like for example the same principle of the drawing program “Paint” – I hope you know what I mean).

I am using the QGIS 2.12.3 - Lyon Version.

Comment: Just draw a in a new shape the region you want to cut out and use it with the clipper tool. The question has already been [answered](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/how-to-clip-a-line-layer-based-on-polygons-with-qgis).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/mtop/speciesgeocoder/wiki/Tutorial-for-creating-polygons-in-QGIS

Comment: I created a new shapefile and tried to use the clipper tool with my new square shapefile and the old one. But my result is just empty. What could that be? I did everything explained in that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4KqMFVHPao

Comment: Its empty probably because of an issue of the [CRS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html). In GIS in most cases you have problems like that, it has something to-do with the CRS, so always be extra careful which CRS you are using. Check again the other link I already posted... [the second anwser](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/169652/53268)

Comment: yes!! that was the problem! thank you so much for your patient!