# Clip shapefile based on another shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, shapely

I have two shapefiles with me, one big and one small. I want to clip part of big shapefile where the small shapefile is located. I tried QGIS vector intersect by geometry, but that is returning me empty file.

Is there any command line argument from gdal that can do the job for me?

Comment: Are the shapefiles in the same coordinate system?

Comment: @smiller No they were not. But now I reprojected them to same coordinate system and tried QJIS intersect but again no result. Is intersect the right command or should I try anything else ?

Comment: It looks like there's a clip tool -- https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/Clip.  Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip

Comment: Great! Added as answer. Please take a moment to mark it as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that the shapefiles are in the same coordinate system, reprojecting if necessary. Then try the Clip tool in QGIS:

```
Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip
```

Additional information on this tool: 
https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/Clip

[Clipping line layer based on polygons with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/clipping-line-layer-based-on-polygons-with-qgis)